# Ignore records I've "skipped"?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `tableA` and `tableB`

```
tableA
------
id
...

tableB
------
id
tableA_id
user_id
```

If a user doesn't have enough information to process an item they "skip" it; this adds a row to `tableB` with the id of the item from `tableA` and their user id.

I want to get rows from `tableA` that a user has not skipped, but other users might have.

For example:

```
userA enters the queue
userA is assigned item1
userA skips item1

userB enters the queue
userB is assigned item1
userB skips item1

userA enters the queue
userA is assigned item2

userB enters the queue
userB is assigned item3

userC enters the queue
userC is assigned item1
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id
WHERE tableB.user_id IS NULL OR tableB.user_id != %s
GROUP BY tableA.id
;
```

This returns `item1` for all other users after it is skipped by any user because `user_id` is no longer `NULL`. This prevents other users from skipping the item.

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tableA
where tableA.id not in
(select tableB.tableA_id from tableB where tableB.user_id = %s)
```

Comment: This worked, but you might want to edit your answer because the subquery isn't valid.

Comment: @Travis, you're right, I forgot the "from" clause, a bad habit of mine. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you query to something like this:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE user_Id = %s) tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id
WHERE tableB.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To return rows from a table where there aren't matching rows from another table, the typical pattern is an anti-join:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM `tableA` a
  LEFT 
  JOIN `tableB` b 
    ON b.tablea_id = a.id
   AND b.user_id   = %s
 WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY a.id
```

The way to look at this, we're returning *all* rows from `a` along with any matching rows from `b`. It's an outer join, so rows from `a` that don't have a match will be returned, along with a dummy placeholder row from `b` that consists of all NULL values.  The trick is the condition in the `WHERE` clause that filters out all rows that had a match, leaving only rows from `a` that didn't have a match.

We can achieve an equivalent result using a NOT EXISTS with correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM `tableA` a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM `tableB` b 
          WHERE b.tablea_id = a.id
            AND b.user_id   = %s
       )
 ORDER
    BY a.id
```